# Appending <noscript> tag to wp_enqueue_scripts or wp_register_script when adding each javascript?

Tags: php, wordpress, noscript

We are running into accessibility errors when running an accessibility checker for our WordPress website. The error messsage thrown is the following: 
"Add a noscript section immediately following the script that provides the same functionality as the script."

My question is, where can I problematically append the the noscript tag?

Example:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/assets/javascripts/superfish/superfish.js'></script>
```

I would like to be able to change it so that it looks like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.egstage.com/wp-content/themes/campus/assets/javascripts/superfish/superfish.js'></script>
<noscript>You need to have JavaScript enabled to view this site.</noscript>
```

I've been trying to solve this for a week now and something I thought would be a quick-fix but instead it is is turning out to be a scavenger hunt.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-Dave

Comment: "same functionality as the script"? good luck with that. if javascript is disable, there is absolutely **NO** way to provide any "functionality" that's now missing/disabled. html is not a programming language, and has no "functionality".

Comment: I'm not an accessibility professional...but how is an empty `<noscript>` tag any more valid than an omitted one?

Comment: It is to appease our lawyers. It is showing 84 errors, all of which state that it needs <noscript> appended. To correct these errors I was hoping there may be an easy way to do this. Is it feasible?

Comment: There is no way to properly do this in WordPress. Instead, you'd have to remove all scripts enqueued with `wp_enqueue_script()` and add the scripts and tags to your site's footer.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do this @mevius? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is just an idea, I didn't test it but it should work (maybe with a little tweaking).

Write a function that replaces `</script>` with `</script><noscript></noscript>` and register it as a [WP filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) for `'script_loader_tag'`:

```
/**
 * The filter. It receives the text of the <script> element prepared 
 * to be put in the page. It appends a <noscript> element after each <script>
 * element and returns the new string.
 *
 * @param string $tag
 * @return string
 */
function add_noscript_tag($tag)
{
    $noScript = <<<END
<noscript>
This functionality is implemented using Javascript. It cannot work without it, etc...
</noscript>
END;

    return str_replace('</script>', '</script>'.$noScript, $tag);
}

// Hook it into WP
add_filter('script_loader_tag', 'add_noscript_tag');
```

Comment: This semi-works.  It reduces the <noscript> errors from 84 (before: https://s32.postimg.org/5jkyuc7ud/before.png) to 42 (after: https://s31.postimg.org/xlmw7o1ob/after.png) . However,  once applied it breaks other plug-ins I use (Revolution Slider and Visual Composer). Any ideas why it might cause this? I'm wondering what steps I can take to identify the cause. It is pretty frustrating to say the least, unfortunately. :/